# Regenerate Magento Cache by Type

Tags: magento2, cache

I need to regenerate Magento cache programmatically either by type or whole.

After cache flush, I don't want to wait for the requests to come and generate the cache passively.

This is needed to avoid slowness in the first requests after cache flush. Also, I have observed that when multiple requests arrive simultaneously, cache generation takes much longer.

Thanks.

Comment: Most people do not FLUSH CACHE why do you?   And how many times per day do you take this action?

Comment: @WilsonHauck I need to do it after deployment and any other changes which need cache flush.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the varnish server.

Comment: Varnish is used for full-page cache and works for public pages only.